# Strange alignment of minipage environments

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I am trying to understand the different alignment options for the `minipage` environment.
The following code draws five top-aligned `minipage` environments, each inside an `\fbox{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][25mm]{0.17\textwidth}\textbf{d}efault\\first\\second\\third\end{minipage}}%
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][25mm][t]{0.17\textwidth}\textbf{t}op\\first\\second\\third\end{minipage}}%
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][25mm][c]{0.17\textwidth}\textbf{c}entred\\first\\second\\third\end{minipage}}%
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][25mm][b]{0.17\textwidth}\textbf{b}otton\\first\\second\\third\end{minipage}}%
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][25mm][s]{0.17\textwidth}\textbf{s}tretch\\first\\second\\third\end{minipage}}%
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

For reasons that I do not understand, the tops of these fboxes are not aligned:

[image]

- the second `minipage` is fractionally lower than the first `minipage`
- the third and fourth `minipage` environments appear to be about `0.5\baselineskip` lower than the first `minipage`

I could believe that the `inner position` is subtley afffecting the vertical space occupied by `minipage` environments *except* that if we change the top alignment of the `minipage` environments to centre or bottom alignment then they are perfectly aligned:

[image]

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the slight mis-alignment of the first two is not due to the different alignment options but because t and d have different heights, if you use the same text in the boxes (a better test for changing the options) then they line up.

[image]

as the minipage are all using `[t]` for the outer alignment they align according to their top reference point along the baseline shown in red.

The first two, and fifth have the first line of a paragraph as the first item, so their reference point is on the baseline of their first line.

The third and fourth have stretchy glue above the paragraph to vertically centre or bottom align, so the reference point is the glue node at the very top edge of the box, so just `\fboxsep` below the black line from `\fbox`.

Comment: Sorry David, I am still confused by boxes three and four. If the gap at the top of these boxes is given by `\fboxsep` shouldn't I be able to remove it by setting `\fboxsep=0pt`? When I try this these two boxes do not move.

Comment: @31415926535897932384 if I set fboxsep=0pt I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmIFl.png) (I also added x either side of the minipages to make baseline clearer)